# onhashchange event doesn't detect changes between "/Home/Index" and "/" - ASP.NET MVC3

Tags: javascript, event-handling

I'm working in a ASP.NET MVC3 web app, and my problem is the following: I want to detect URL changes using:

```
window.onhashchange = function (event) { 
    //some stuff...
};
```

and it works perfectly... But, it works perfectly while in the url always appears:

> **'localhost:[port]/Home/Index'**

or in some cases, url changes to:

> **'localhost:[port]/Home/Index#'**

When the user changes the url (for example, he deletes '**/Home/Index**'), the pages is reloaded (the url is '**localhost:[port]/**') but when user presses back button and back again to '**/Home/Index**' onhashchange event
doesn't detect this change. Why? '**/Home/Index**' and '**/**' is the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The hash is what comes *after* the `#` symbol in the url.

If the current url is:

```
http://localhost:12345/Home/Index#chapter-1
```

and somebody clicks a link like this one: `<a href="#chapter-2">Chapter 2</a>` then the hash part of the url will change causing `window.onhashchange` to be fired. Navigating to another page does not fire the onhashchange event because the hash didn't change on the new page.

```js
window.onhashchange = function(e) {
      var log = document.getElementById("log");

      log.innerText = "Event: Hash changed " + location.hash;

      window.setTimeout(function() {
        log.innerText = "Event: ";
      }, 3000);
    }
```

```html
<div id="log">Event:</div>

<ul>
  <li><a href="#chapter1">Change hash to chapter 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#chapter2">Change hash to chapter 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Change hash to nothing</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" onclick="location.reload()">reload page</a></li>
</ul>
```